# Crystal for visual studio CRforVS_13_0_1 also called crredist2008_x64

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have an old app that runs on windows server 2008, and it’s moving forward to windows server 2012
The app uses crystal reports for visual studio version CRforVS_13_0_1  also called crredist2008_x64

I haven’t been able to find any documentation, I was wondering if anyone knows if this crystal runtime will run on windows server 2012?